# What's faster/should be rather used for short(ish) Strings: Split or Substring?

Tags: swift, optimization, split, substring

Swift 5, Xcode 10.

I'm looping through an array of Strings (size probably < 20), each of them looks something like this:

```
johnsmith.20190202102030.conf
janedoe.19700101115959.conf
```

I know the first part (the name) beforehand but want to extract the middle part (birthday: 8, 12 or 14 characters long).

Version 1:

```
let f = "johnsmith.20190202102030.conf"
let name = "johnsmith"

let start = f.index(f.startIndex, offsetBy: name.count+1)
let end = f.index(f.startIndex, offsetBy: f.count-5)

let birthday = String(f[start..<end])
```

Version 2:

```
let f = "johnsmith.20190202102030.conf"
let farr = f.split(separator: ".").map(String.init)
let birthday = farr[1]
```

I'm currently only doing this for 10 Strings and (of course) didn't notice any difference in speed. Even with 100 Strings there probably won't be much of a difference anyway but I'm curious:

Ignoring the length of the code and potential errors, is there a reason (apart from personal preference) to prefer using one version over the other (e.g. speed with 100k Strings - I'm not asking for actual measurements!)?

Comment: Why not try it yourself and measure which version is faster?

Comment: You can also try `"johnsmith.20190202102030.conf".drop(while: { $0 != "." }).dropFirst().dropLast(5)`

Comment: @wvteijlingen There are never going to be a thousand Strings, usually there won't even be more than 10 because I already get rid of the unimportant ones beforehand, so measurements with that scale don't even matter (one of the reasons why I'm not interested in actual measurements). If it all only comes down to preference, that's fine but being still fairly new to Swift, it would still be helpful if anyone knew about e.g. little tweaks that make one version, let's call it "better".

Comment: @user28434 A one-liner, nice. Going to try that tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: But if actual measurements and performance don't matter, why don't you just pick what you think is more readable? Otherwise it is just a matter of opinion, which is not a very good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Writing code that is more easily understood and maintainable is far more important than worrying about performance until there is an actual performance problem.

Comment: @wvteijlingen Sure, it would be interesting to see exact measurements but I'm not going to ask anyone to do them for me (and don't want anyone to do them for me!). That's why I'm more interested in the "tweaks", like I said. If both versions are fine in term of performance and it doesn't matter at all unless I'm using them for thousands of Strings, then that's an answer I'll accept. Readability is a good point of course.

Comment: Apart from speed, readability and personal preference, is there any other reason why you should choose one version over the other? Or are those the only three points it comes down to - at least in my case?

Answer (score 1):

From my very rough testing, it seems that the substring version is faster. However, in your case I would opt for using the version using `split`. The code is much more readable to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If you already did the testing, at what point did it start making an actual difference?

Comment: Depends on what you would call an "actual difference". When running it once it there is already a difference, even though it's absolutely negligible.

Comment: So basically what I already expected: Unless I'm using it for thousands of Strings, it won't matter speed-wise, right?

Comment: That is correct. Don't focus on performance here, just write code that is readable and understandable.